# How to display a Powershell output array in a list box

Tags: wpf, powershell

Trying to figure out how to get powershell outputs to display correctly in a listbox working with a WPF Powershell project. I have an example where in powershell it displays fine like below.

[image: PS output]

However my listbox it will show as below

[image: Listbox Output]

I want it to just show the SamAccountName so PS.Test in this case. Used the below line but to no avail Not entirely sure how to do this tried a few things

```
$ListBoxLeft.DisplayMember = "SamAccountName";
```

The command i was using is

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$query*'") | Select SamAccountName | Sort -Property SamAccountName
```

there is a textbox where the name is pulled from.
All new to me this side of it so trying to play around and learn so i can utilise the functions in various scripts in the future.

Code for the task which populates the listbox

```
function SearchDGUserClick
{
    param($sender, $e)

 $query = $DGUserSearchText.Text
 $UserSearch = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$query*'") | Select SamAccountName | Sort -Property SamAccountName

  foreach ($item in $UserSearch) {
    $DGMemberSearchListBox.Items.Add($item)
    
  }


}
```

Comment: Try casting the source collection as an `[IList[object]]`, eg. `$ListBoxLeft.DataSource = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new($listOfUserObjects)`

Comment: What you are seeing in Powershell is the output of Format-Table.  How did Format-Table get into the picture?  When you let some output emerge from the end of the pipeline,  PS converts it to printable form before putting it on the console.

Comment: @WalterMitty that would be the default formatting of the output from `(Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$query*'") | Select SamAccountName | Sort -Property SamAccountName`

Comment: Thank you @MathiasR.Jessen i will have a look and give this a go.

Comment: `$DGMemberSearchListBox.Items.Add($item.SamAccountName)`

Comment: @mm8 code added to the original post

Comment: Thank you @Theo that worked perfectly... Silly really it didnt click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the value of the `SamAccountName` property to the `Items` collection:

```
foreach ($item in $UserSearch) {
  $DGMemberSearchListBox.Items.Add($item.SamAccountName)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As also commented to theo. Worked a charm. Silly how it didn't click something so simple... Good to learn :)